# Fixed header overflowing parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with a fixed header.

As you can see from the snippet below, the page isn't necessarily as wide as the viewport. To ensure the header width remains in sync with the rest of the page (and doesn't overflow), I use the following CSS on the app bar:

```
max-width: inherit;
width: inherit;
```

**Simple fixed header example:**

```css
.page {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding-top: 64px;
}

.app-bar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="app-bar">App bar</div>
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat nibh ac magna consequat luctus. Sed scelerisque mi nec tellus posuere pellentesque. Praesent varius et risus non fringilla. Maecenas nec sodales nulla, in ultricies erat. Phasellus
    purus urna, suscipit quis dui nec, sollicitudin facilisis ipsum. In varius, dolor quis vestibulum finibus, nisl mauris interdum purus, tempus malesuada ante metus at sem. Nunc mauris tellus, blandit at ipsum non, convallis fringilla risus. Etiam vitae
    sapien id dui aliquet tincidunt ut ut odio. Phasellus non metus egestas, faucibus nisi sed, lacinia dui. Donec convallis massa mi, quis dapibus magna sodales at. Sed gravida, justo ut placerat rhoncus, ligula quam fermentum magna, id vehicula turpis
    arcu a enim. Vivamus eget volutpat nunc. Nam consequat sapien non sodales euismod. Integer euismod orci diam, et consequat mi feugiat sed. Proin aliquam porta nisi, ut aliquam enim facilisis ut.
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I need to make some changes to the page structure to allow a full-height fixed left nav drawer. In order to do so, I need to create space by shifting the entire content to the right.

**Required fixed header functionality:**

```css
.page {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-content {
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.main {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding-top: 64px;
}

.app-bar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="app-content">
    <div class="app-bar">App bar</div>
    <div class="main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat nibh ac magna consequat luctus. Sed scelerisque mi nec tellus posuere pellentesque. Praesent varius et risus non fringilla. Maecenas nec sodales nulla, in ultricies erat. Phasellus
      purus urna, suscipit quis dui nec, sollicitudin facilisis ipsum. In varius, dolor quis vestibulum finibus, nisl mauris interdum purus, tempus malesuada ante metus at sem. Nunc mauris tellus, blandit at ipsum non, convallis fringilla risus. Etiam
      vitae sapien id dui aliquet tincidunt ut ut odio. Phasellus non metus egestas, faucibus nisi sed, lacinia dui. Donec convallis massa mi, quis dapibus magna sodales at. Sed gravida, justo ut placerat rhoncus, ligula quam fermentum magna, id vehicula
      turpis arcu a enim. Vivamus eget volutpat nunc. Nam consequat sapien non sodales euismod. Integer euismod orci diam, et consequat mi feugiat sed. Proin aliquam porta nisi, ut aliquam enim facilisis ut.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the result is that the `app-bar` doesn't sync across the full width - instead it overflows the `page container`.

If I remove the width from app-content, the `app-bar` shrinks to it's content width.

What I'm looking for is to make the `app-bar` the same width as the `app-content container`, as it does in the first snippet.

Any advice appreciated as I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: why not just set your max-width to 250px if you know the container has a max width of 400 and the sidebar is 150? Also set your width to 100%

Comment: You know when you get code blindness? Doh! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `width` of your page is constant you can just give the `app-bar` it's desired `width` in this case `250px` if I'm understanding you correctly:

```css
.page {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-content {
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.main {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding-top: 64px;
}

.app-bar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="app-content">
    <div class="app-bar">App bar</div>
    <div class="main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat nibh ac magna consequat luctus. Sed scelerisque mi nec tellus posuere pellentesque. Praesent varius et risus non fringilla. Maecenas nec sodales nulla, in ultricies erat. Phasellus
      purus urna, suscipit quis dui nec, sollicitudin facilisis ipsum. In varius, dolor quis vestibulum finibus, nisl mauris interdum purus, tempus malesuada ante metus at sem. Nunc mauris tellus, blandit at ipsum non, convallis fringilla risus. Etiam
      vitae sapien id dui aliquet tincidunt ut ut odio. Phasellus non metus egestas, faucibus nisi sed, lacinia dui. Donec convallis massa mi, quis dapibus magna sodales at. Sed gravida, justo ut placerat rhoncus, ligula quam fermentum magna, id vehicula
      turpis arcu a enim. Vivamus eget volutpat nunc. Nam consequat sapien non sodales euismod. Integer euismod orci diam, et consequat mi feugiat sed. Proin aliquam porta nisi, ut aliquam enim facilisis ut.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can do that due to browser compatibility, but I would suggest using `position: sticky`.

```css
.page {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-content {
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.app-bar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 64px;
  max-width: inherit;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="app-bar">App bar</div>
  <div class="app-content">
    <div class="main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat nibh ac magna consequat luctus. Sed scelerisque mi nec tellus posuere pellentesque. Praesent varius et risus non fringilla. Maecenas nec sodales nulla, in ultricies erat. Phasellus
      purus urna, suscipit quis dui nec, sollicitudin facilisis ipsum. In varius, dolor quis vestibulum finibus, nisl mauris interdum purus, tempus malesuada ante metus at sem. Nunc mauris tellus, blandit at ipsum non, convallis fringilla risus. Etiam
      vitae sapien id dui aliquet tincidunt ut ut odio. Phasellus non metus egestas, faucibus nisi sed, lacinia dui. Donec convallis massa mi, quis dapibus magna sodales at. Sed gravida, justo ut placerat rhoncus, ligula quam fermentum magna, id vehicula
      turpis arcu a enim. Vivamus eget volutpat nunc. Nam consequat sapien non sodales euismod. Integer euismod orci diam, et consequat mi feugiat sed. Proin aliquam porta nisi, ut aliquam enim facilisis ut.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately "sticky" has a number of issues across browsers and can't be used in production.